# IllegalStateException: Error occurred while storing entity <entity> An entity copy <entity> was already assigned to a different entity <entity_copy>

Tags: hibernate, persistence

After a lot of googling I didn't find answer to my question, except downgrade hibernate version. But I faced this situation at similar post dated as 2003 year.

**What the problem:**

```
//in the  first session I do
session1.save(entity);
session1.getTransaction().commit();
session1.close();

//in the second session (after client response), I get back the serialized copy of the entity
entityCopy = deserialize(jsonString);
entityCopy.setEntityDetail(newDetail); //1
session2.merge(entityCopy); //EXCEPTION!
```

**If comment string 1, all works fine!**

**Exception:**

**IllegalStateException**: *Error occurred while storing entity #4700 An entity copy #4700 was already assigned to a different entity @2e7b134a*

**Questions:**

1. *What is wrong in my sitation?*
2. As I understand, merge() operation was implemented for those cases, when we alreadty have the entity copy in cache. *Am I wrong?*

**PS**

1. If it is important **Entity -> EntityDetail** are linked with ***lazy, orphanRemoval = true, one-2-one*** relationship
2. I overrided equals() and hashCode() methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem in the next way: it is necessary to *merge deserialized entity before you proceed some changes to it*. (the only change is in the 2 string):

```
//in the  first session I do
session1.save(entity);
session1.getTransaction().commit();
session1.close();

//in the second session (after client response), I get back the serialized copy of the entity
entityCopy = deserialize(jsonString);
entityCopy = (Entity) session.merge(entityCopy); //2
entityCopy.setEntityDetail(newDetail); 
session2.merge(entityCopy); //all works fine
```